# How to integrate Air watch SDK in Xamarin cross platform application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to integrate Airwatch SDK 1.4.0.1 in one of my project, how can I integrate AWSDK in cross platform application which will support both iOS and android, or is there any work around to do it so.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to integrate native SDK's that don't have nuget packages, you are entering the territory of Intermediate Xamarin Development. What you need to do is create "native bindings in C#".

There's many ways of doing it, and can take between 30 minutes to a 5 days to do. If you watch [this video](https://youtu.be/NyqxScrnJKw?t=3751) starting around 50:00, presented by the Lead of the Xamarin Components team, Jonathan Dick, you will learn one way of doing the entire binding process for iOS cocoa pods and Android Maven packages.